# Is `Request.IsLocal` secure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, request

Is the property `Request.IsLocal` spoofable, or 100% trustworthy?

I want to be certain a request is coming from my box only.

Comment: See http://forums.asp.net/t/1065813.aspx/1

Comment: As it just check for IP address, I fear it can be spoofed if the browser will send its IP as 127.0.0.1 (fake browser that is)

Comment: Ah yeah - the browser can fake what it wants, it wont ever get an open TCP connection fully established unless the server can send it back packets. Ergo no fake.

Comment: I don't think 127.0.0.1 can be spoofed - but have nothing to back that up. Perhaps the guys & gals (if any :P) at serverfault.com may be able to help you on whether 127.0.0.1 is spoofable on your server - that's server/hardware dependent. If possible it would certainly require some effort :P

Comment: it is spoofable when done "rootkit-way", special kernel module which in this case even need to change the behaviour of other kernel modules (network stack)... that would have to be on your box and then the attacker would be able to connect from somewhere else... or your app is running inside a debugger or on a "adversial CLR" or or... I am sure there are much more ways than the 3 I thought up while writing this comment...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unless someone manipulates your TCP stack it is fully trustable.

it basically is an analysis of the network stack from the IIS layer on whether the request originated locally - most likely by coming from a 127.0.0.x address (yes, localhost is the whole at that time C network, not just 127.0.0.1).

There is no way to establish a TCp connection with a fake origin, so this data can be trusted.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1065813.aspx/1

indicates via decompiling it checks on 127.0.0.1 and ::1 - both are the common localhost addresses.

Again, and still, this is totally not fakeable unless you manipualte the network stack or the .net framework classes.

Comment: Great News, thanks. I'm not worried about physical security (yet).

Comment: As futher explanation: It can not be faked because it requires an established connection which requires - handshake (request, response, then data). You can fake it on the way, but if you choose a diffferent routed IP address the response goes to the wrong host, so no data can be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Thought it was because it relies on the IP, however it doesn't work for me on Azure. So, to answer your question it's not 100%, no.