# Is localhost safe to check as a security condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I have an `HttpHandler` that does something but I want don't want it to run when running on my local machine. For now, I simply comment out the handler in the `web.config` file when I'm running the site in Visual Studio, and uncomment it when I deploy the site: cumbersome. I want to add a condition to check if the site is running on my local machine like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Current.Request.Url.Host != "localhost") { DoSomething(); }
}
```

Is this safe or is it possible that when I deploy the condition will not trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead I'd recommend you use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check [`Request.IsLocal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148821/request-islocal).

Whether checking for local(host) works depends on the rest of your setup, for example when it is called by a site or proxy on the same machine that can cause the request to appear to come from the same machine, though it actually is external.

> For now, I simply comment out the handler in the web.config

It sounds like you could use a [configuration transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx) instead, so the handler doesn't get included in deploy builds.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer; Joe beat you by just a few seconds but upvoted and I'll look into config transforms!