# How do I add an WebApiConfig to my UmbracoApiController?

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, asp.net-apicontroller, umbraco8

I'm trying to create a APIcontroller for my Umbraco V8 package. The API is working fine but I only want my backoffice AngularControllers to have access to the API. I wish to create a attribute like described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30573590/11409365. This way only the localmachine can access the API.

I don't think it's relevant but this is the code in my APIController

```
    public class PackageApiController : UmbracoApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetString()
        {
            return "Test";
        }

     }
```

But where do I add my WebApiConfig class and how do I make sure the ApiController uses this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be sufficient to use UmbracoAuthorizedApiController instead of UmbracoApiController? UmbracoAuthorizedApiController requires the caller to be logged into the backoffice.

Have a look here (there's also an option to add an attribute to your UmbracoApiController): https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/authorization

Comment: @Bart How are you calling this API? Where from?